# How do I create a project in WebStorm for Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, webstorm

I have created a project in WebStorm by watching a tutorial [Node.js + Express - Tutorial - Insert and Get Data with MongoDB](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZKwrOXl5TDI) (check from 1:49 to 1:53 (I get error when I run www.js))

when i run localhost:8000, im able to insert the data,but i am not able to get the data,i get the below error

> GET / 200 44.467 ms - 1968 GET /stylesheets/style.css 200 27.109 ms -
>   962 GET /favicon.ico 404 6.245 ms - 199 POST /insert 302 245.066 ms -
>   46 GET / 304 5.643 ms - - GET /stylesheets/style.css 304 1.362 ms - -
>   C:\Users\ptech-user\WebstormProjects\aishuuu\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:421
>             throw err
>             ^
>
> AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: null == 'MongoError: failed to connect
>   to server [localhost:27017] on first connect [MongoError: connect
>   ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017]'
>       at C:\Users\ptech-user\WebstormProjects\aishuuu\routes\index.js:37:12
>       at connectCallback (C:\Users\ptech-user\WebstormProjects\aishuuu\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:515:5)
>       at C:\Users\ptech-user\WebstormProjects\aishuuu\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:418:11
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:131:7)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

[GitHub link for source code](http://github.com/mschwarzmueller/nodejs-basics-tutorial)

How to solve this?

[im not able to get the data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BQYdr.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have and 'http://' module instead of this you have 'http'.
Edit the require statement in the following way

Incorrect

```
var http=require('http://');
```

Correct

```
var http=require('http');
```

For a better understanding of what you do take a more in-depth tutorial about Node.Js and how it works.
Resource:
https://www.guru99.com/node-js-tutorial.html

Comment: yea thankyou! i am now able to insert the data but not get the data! i have edited my question! please help

Comment: please do reply!